# How to customize x and y axes in sympy?

Tags: matplotlib, plot, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, sympy

I've created a plot in sympy and would like to customize the x- and y-axis. I want to turn them into red and have them be dashed. I've looked around and tried some stuff but nothing seems to work, such as:

```
plt.axhline(linewidth = 1, linestyle = '--', color = 'red')
plt.axvline(linewidth = 1, linestyle = '--', color = 'red')
```

Are there some ways to do this that would actually work?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE**
Sympy's `plot(...)._backend.ax` now (Nov 2023) returns not a single Axes object but a list of Axes — usually with a single element.
You must write `p._backend.ax[0].method_of_axes()`
———————————————————————————————————————
Sympy's source code of `*/sympy/plotting/plot.py` has this comment:

> Especially if you need publication ready graphs and this module is
> not enough for you - just get the `_backend` attribute and add
> whatever you want directly to it. In the case of matplotlib (the
> common way to graph data in python) just copy `_backend.fig` which
> is the figure and `_backend.ax` which is the axis and work on them
> as you would on any other matplotlib object.

This means that, in general, Sympy's plots can be tweaked modifying the underlying `Axes` object, that can be accessed using the `_backend` attribute of the Sympy's `plot` instance.

To address your specific requests, each `Axes` contains an `OrderedDict` of `Spine` objects, the one that you want to modify are the `'bottom`' and the `'left'` ones (to modify these objects you have to use their `set_x` methods)

```
In [33]: from sympy import * 
    ...: x = symbols('x') 
    ...: p = plot(sin(x))

    ...: for spine in ('bottom', 'left'):
    ...:     p._backend.ax.spines[spine].set_linestyle((0, (5, 10))) 
    ...:     p._backend.ax.spines[spine].set_edgecolor('red')

    ...: p._backend.fig.savefig('Figure_1.png')
```

produces
[image]

Note: if one uses `p.save('...')` then the figure is reset and they'll miss any tweaking they've made, hence I used the `savefig` method of the underlying `Figure` object, accessed again using the `_backend` attribute.